# why i can't update my data with ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i tried to update my data with ajax and php, it's got the message that the process was success. but when i check in my database there is nothing change and i check on my concole log if there is an error but nothing too. here is my script for ajax:

```
$('#modal').find('#plc_form').on('submit','#ed_form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData();

    //Form data
    var form_data = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.each(form_data, function (key, input) {
    data.append(input.name, input.value);
    });

    //profil
    var profil = $('input[name="gbr_profil"]')[0].files;
    data.append("gbr_profil", profil[0]);


    //File data
    var file_data = $('input[name="galeri[]"]')[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < file_data.length; i++) {
    data.append("galeri", file_data[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'template/proses.php?p=update',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
        $('#modal').modal('hide');
        $('#msg').html(msg);
        listdata();
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });

    });
```

and this is process on php side

```
$page = $_GET['p'];
if($page == 'update'){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $nama = $_POST['nama_sekolah'];
    $npsn = $_POST['npsn_sekolah'];
    $alamat = $_POST['alamat_sekolah'];
    $tahun = $_POST['tahun_sekolah'];
    $kepsek = $_POST['kepala_sekolah'];
    $telpon = $_POST['telepon_sekolah'];
    $fax = $_POST['fax_sekolah'];
    $email = $_POST['email_sekolah'];
    $website = $_POST['website_sekolah'];
    $akredit = $_POST['optionsRadios'];
    $nilai = $_POST['akreditasi_sekolah'];
    $gambar = $_FILES['gbr_profil']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gbr_profil']['tmp_name'], "profil/".$gambar);

    $db->query("UPDATE profil_sekolah SET nama_sekolah='$nama', nspn='$npsn', alamat='$alamat', tahun_berdiri='$tahun', nama_kepsek='$kepsek', telp='$telpon', fax='$fax', email='$email', website='$website', akreditasi='$akredit',nilai_akreditasi='$nilai', gar_profil='$gambar' where id_sekolah='$id'");

    $lintang = $_POST['lintang'];
    $bujur = $_POST['bujur'];

    $db->query("UPDATE lokasi set sekolah='$nama', bujur='$bujur',lintang='$lintang' where id_lokasi='$id'");

    $stf_lk = $_POST['g_stf_lk'];
    $stf_pr = $_POST['g_stf_pr'];
    $nostf_lk = $_POST['g_nostf_lk'];
    $nostf_pr = $_POST['g_nostf_pr'];
    $hnr_lk = $_POST['g_hnr_lk'];
    $hnr_pr = $_POST['g_hnr_pr'];
    $pns_lk = $_POST['adm_pns_lk'];
    $pns_pr = $_POST['adm_pns_pr'];
    $ad_hnr_lk = $_POST['adm_hnr_lk'];
    $ad_hnr_pr = $_POST['adm_hnr_pr'];

    $db->query("UPDATE pegawai SET guru_stf_lk='$stf_lk', guru_stf_pr='$stf_pr', guru_n_stf_lk='$nostf_lk', guru_n_stf_pr='$nostf_pr', guru_hnr_lk='$hnr_lk', guru_hnr_pr='$hnr_pr', admin_pns_lk='$pns_lk', admin_pns_pr'$pns_pr', admin_hnr_lk='$ad_hnr_lk', admin_hnr_pr='$ad_hnr_pr' where id_pegawai='$id'");

}

if($db){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable' style='padding-top: 10px;'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>data berhasil diubah</div>";
} else {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable' style='padding-top: 10px;'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>data gagal diubah</div>";
}
```

and the ID i used to differ each data like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $row['0']; ?>">
```

i don't know where is wrong or error with my script, i will be gladly if there is an answer

Comment: `if($db){` is telling you that that you have a database object, not whether the query was successful or not.

Comment: actually i use more than one sql statement, and i dont know how to combine them in one variable so i can make if function.

Comment: The answer shows how to check if the update was successful.  I commented that it wasn't how it should be done only because the answer used the same insecure terminology that yours uses.  All you have to do to make yours check correctly is `$q1 = $db->query("UPDATE lokasi set ...);` and `$q2 = $db->query("UPDATE pegawai SET ...);`  `if($q1 && $q2) { ... `

Comment: But once again, doing the query that way is insecure and ripe for sql injection.  You really need to learn parameterized queries.

Comment: hmm, `$q1` and `$q2` were probably bad choices for var names.  `$result1` and `$result2` are probably more meaningful...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to process data before passing it, you can simply acheive this by

```
$('#modal').find('#plc_form').on('submit','#ed_form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    var formData = new FormData($("#ed_form")[0]);  // Your form id

    $.ajax({
            url: "template/proses.php?p=update",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(done){
              console.log(done)
            },
            error: function(error){
              console.log(error);
            }
        });

});
```

And also you should update query condition like below

```
$sql = "UPDATE profil_sekolah SET nama_sekolah='$nama', nspn='$npsn', alamat='$alamat', tahun_berdiri='$tahun', nama_kepsek='$kepsek', telp='$telpon', fax='$fax', email='$email', website='$website', akreditasi='$akredit',nilai_akreditasi='$nilai', gar_profil='$gambar' where id_sekolah='$id'";

if($db->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable' style='padding-top: 10px;'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>data berhasil diubah</div>";
} else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable' style='padding-top: 10px;'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>data gagal diubah</div>";
    }
```

Comment: That will work, but it's ***not*** how you ***should*** update the query. It's open to injection.  Since we don't know what the properties of `$db` are, it's impossible to know exactly how the statements should be crafted... but it would probably be along the lines of `$db->prepare("UPDATE profil_sekolah SET nama_sekolah=?, nspn=? ... snip ...) ; `  `if($db->execute(array($nama,$nspn, ...)) { echo success... } else { echo failure... }`

Comment: i use `$db` as variable for mysql connection like this `$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","skriboo");`